# .NET Core 2 programmatically authentcation on Keycloak example

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to authenticate through a device (it's a barcode reader) that use .NET Core. I'm a newbie on .NET Core.

Now I need to write some program that gives me the possibility that given a username/password I make authentication on a Keycloak server with openidconnect. Is there some sample that shows how from a username/password string I can make the authentication programmatically?

I find a lot of examples that use .NET Core as a server that has Controllers that exposes rest API for user that have to be authenticated. But I need some example/hint to follow where the .NET Core makes the request.

**Update**

I could figure out (with curl) what exactly I have to do. Two calls to the Keycloak server.

1. call:

http://keycloakserver/auth/realms/realmName/protocol/openid-connect/token?grant_type=password&client_id=demo-app&username=username&password=password

This gives me back an object containing the *access_token*.

2. invoke the secured service adding in the header

"Authorization: bearer +*access_token*"

I try to develop this two calls with .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

I found this way to resolve it. But I'm sure is not the best way. I think there is a lot of improvement of security:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "client_id", "myClientId" },
            { "grant_type", "password" },
            { "username", "usernaName" },
            { "password", "password" }
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
         var response = await client.PostAsync("http://domain/auth/realms/realmName/protocol/openid-connect/token", content);
         var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         var responseToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseToken>(responseString);

        Console.WriteLine("accessToken: " + responseToken.AccessToken);

        var client2 = new HttpClient();
        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json"));
        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");
        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer "+ responseToken.AccessToken);

        var dataResponse = client2.GetStreamAsync("http://serviceDomain/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts");

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Weather>));
        var tempData = serializer.ReadObject(await dataResponse) as List<Weather>;
        Console.WriteLine(tempData);
```

If you have a better solution then don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: What is ResponseToken? I don't see where that is defined.